# Easiest way to create detailed animations

Tags: video, animation

I'm looking for a software to create animated gifs (or webm's) like the following:

http://gph.is/2fvtMv7

How do you think these animations are created? Of course I could do this layer by layer in e.g. Photoshop but look at the delay effect when the conveyor starts to move - wouldn't it cost days to create things like this? There must be an easier way.

Comment: <comments removed> Folks, if you have an answer, please post it below. Comments to not have the features designed to vet whatever you say here. Comments are not for answers; answers are for answers. Thanks.